# Get CheckBox value from child form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a mainForm  and owner form cameraViewVS(child). I have a checkBox in the second form and i want when i check or uncheck i retrieve its value in the first form, i used the propertyName like this in mainForm

```
public bool propertyZoomCam
{
  get { return f1.checkBoxZoomCam.Checked; }
}
```

I call this property in f1 when i show the instance of f2 once only.

```
public void timer()
{
  for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++)        
  {            
    cameraInstance[l].Start();
    if (cameraInstance[l].MoveDetection == true)
    {
      foreach (Form S in Application.OpenForms)
      {
        var frm = S as Formes.CameraViewVS;
        if (frm != null && frm.Addresse == cameraInstance[l].adresse) {
          // Match, activate it
          cameraInstance[l].MoveDetection = false;
          frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
          frm.Activate();
          return;
        }
      }
      // No match found, create a new one
      var f1 = new Formes.CameraViewVS(cameraInstance[l], adresseIPArray[l]);
      f1.Show(this);
      if(propertyZoomCam)
        zoom = 15;
    }
  }
}
```

I retrieve just the first false value because its value at beginning is false, and when I change the check or uncheck i don't retreive its value.

Any help?

Comment: If the checkbox is in f2, why does the property read `f1.checkBoxZoomCam.Checked`?  Does f1 have a checkbox of the same name?  CameraVireVS *looks* like a child form, but you are calling it f1.

Comment: no, the "f1" in the code is just the instance of second form Formes.CameraViewVS and the checkbox is in this form an di retrieve its value in the mainform.

Comment: It sounds like CameraViewVS should raise an event that the checkbox was checked and have the main form listen for it and set the `Zoom` value then.  Your posted code never reaches `If (propertyZoomCam)` if the form is found in the collection.

Comment: could you give me an example how to make an event on CameraViewVS and listener in mainForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following changes in the code:

1. Declare a variable at form level that will hold the reference to child form.
2. Now replace the variable f1  and frm  with frmCamera in Timer function and don't declare the variable f1 and frm in timer function.

3.Now update the property code.

```
Formes.CameraViewVS frmCamera;

public bool propertyZoomCam
{
    get 
    {
        if (frmCamera!=null)
            return frmCamera.checkBoxZoomCam.Checked; 
        else 
            return false;
    }
}


public void timer()
{
  for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++)        
  {            
    cameraInstance[l].Start();
    if (cameraInstance[l].MoveDetection == true)
    {
      foreach (Form S in Application.OpenForms)
      {
        frmCamera = S as Formes.CameraViewVS;
        if (frmCamera != null && frmCamera.Addresse == cameraInstance[l].adresse) {
          // Match, activate it
          cameraInstance[l].MoveDetection = false;
          frmCamera.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
          frmCamera.Activate();
          return;
        }
      }
      // No match found, create a new one
      frmCamera = new Formes.CameraViewVS(cameraInstance[l], adresseIPArray[l]);
      frmCamera.Show(this);
      if(propertyZoomCam)
        zoom = 15;
    }
  }
}
```

You was losting the reference of Camera form when timer event is fired again, so now we are storing the form in same object that is being used in property.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple oif things you should review here:

1. As noted in above answer, you are referencing a local variable in your property code.  This will only work when you access the property in the scope of the creation of that variable, which considerably limits the use you are looking to implement.  I won't say you should never do this, but I can't come up with a valid use case.
2. The call to Show() creates a modeless form and returns immediately, so unless the onload code modifies the status of the checkbox, it will almost never be any different than the status at creation, which you already know.
3. Lastly, and most importantly with respect to your end goal, using a timer is probably an inefficient way to handle check-box changes.  If you want your app to react in the parent form when the checkbox in the child form is clicked, you need to make use of events.  When the child form detects that the user changed the status of the checkbox, it should trigger an event.  The mainform can listen for this event and respond appropriately instead of waiting for the next timer cycle.  You should read up on *events* and *delegates* to implement this.  There are many questions on SO that address those techniques.